# Cannot get link from file sent up to dropbox getting message WaitingForActivation

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

I'm attempting to upload a file and then get a link for it once it has been uploaded.

I seem to be sending up the file without a problem but when I go to obtain a link to the file, it sends back WaitingForActivation.

Here's my code:

```
private async Task ChunkUpload2(DropboxClient client, string folder, string fileName)
{
  try
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Starting file upload...");
    var path = $"{folder}/{Path.GetFileName(fileName)}";

    // Chunk size is 128KB.
    const int chunkSize = 4096 * 1024;

    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine($"File does not exist: {fileName}");
      Console.WriteLine();
      return;
    }

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)))
    {
      int numChunks = (int) Math.Ceiling((double) stream.Length / chunkSize);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
      string sessionId = null;

      if (numChunks == 1)
      {
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, chunkSize))
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"Sending file: {path}");
          var tst = await client.Files.UploadAsync(path, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body: memStream);
          //Console.WriteLine(updated.Result);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        for (var idx = 0; idx < numChunks; idx++)
        {
          Console.WriteLine($"Uploading chunk {idx + 1} / {numChunks}.");
          var byteRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);

          using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, byteRead))
          {
            var cursor = new UploadSessionCursor(sessionId, (ulong) (chunkSize * idx));

            if (idx == numChunks - 1)
            {
              Console.WriteLine($"Finalizing file: {path}");
              var response = await client.Files.UploadSessionFinishAsync(cursor, new CommitInfo(path), memStream);
            }

            else
            {
              await client.Files.UploadSessionAppendV2Async(cursor, body: memStream);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      var url = string.Empty;
      var link = await client.Sharing.ListSharedLinksAsync(path);

      if (link.Links.Count == 0)
      {
        var result = client.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(path);
        url = result.Result.Url;
      }
      else
      {
        url = link.Links[0].Url;
      }

      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Dropbox Download Link:");
      Console.WriteLine(url);
      Console.WriteLine();
      //Console.ReadKey();
    }


  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
  }

}
```

The last portion, at `CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync` is where it's giving me back no share urls. Instead it returns the code above.

I'm getting this message:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to 'Active' this file? I'm assuming I'm missing something?

Comment: It looks like you're missing an `await` on that `client.Sharing.CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync` call.

Comment: @Greg so simple and I overlooked it. Post it as your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again.